# Prove or disprove $span({v_0, v_1,...,v_n}) = span({v_0, v_1 - v_0, ..., v_n-v_0})$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, vector-fields

As the title says. I am under the impression that the right hand side refers to an equivalence class (since we can show that the set ${v_0, v_1-v_0, ..., v_n - v_0}$ is a subspace and therefore the differences are contained in that subspace), and that if we take $v_0$ to be the zero vector, which we know is an element of all vector spaces, then we show equality. However, I'm not sure if this is the right approach.

Comment: Use the fact that $v_i=(v_i-v_0)+v_0\in span({v_0, v_1 - v_0, ..., v_n-v_0})$

Comment: You cannot prove a statement that is supposed to work for any values of $v_0,v_1,\ldots, v_n$ by chosing $v_0$ to be a specific, "convinient" value. Setting $v_0$ to the zero vector proves that the equation is true for some values $v_i$, but by no means proves it for all values.